# Calculating MyQL PXC gcache

Tags: mysql, percona

I was trying ti figure out how to calculate the right gcache for my server and came across the following post discussing just how to do that:

```
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/09/08/calculate-correct-size-percona-xtradb-clusters-gcache/
```

In the post, the talk about doing the following to get the values needed for the calculation:

```
show global status like 'wsrep_received_bytes';
show global status like 'wsrep_replicated_bytes';
select sleep(60);
show global status like 'wsrep_received_bytes';
show global status like 'wsrep_replicated_bytes';
```

My question is, will running the select sleep(60) in production block all reads on MySQL (by keeping the mysqld thread busy)? How can i calculate the best gcache value in production?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is multi-threaded. The sleep(60) will eat one connection (and possibly a thread), but will not block the entire server. The max number of connections and number of concurrently running threads are set in `my.cnf`. (In a production environment, you may also have ProxySQL, etc. settings too).

If you're worried about eating a connection, the easy way to avoid it is to disconnect, sleep, and reconnect. E.g., in shell:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
mysql -e "show global status like 'wsrep_received_bytes'; show global status like 'wsrep_replicated_bytes';"
sleep 60
mysql -e "show global status like 'wsrep_received_bytes'; show global status like 'wsrep_replicated_bytes';"
```

Similar can be done in most programming/scripting languages.

A word of warning: It seems like you need to learn a lot more about MySQL before attempting to tune it. Especially in a production environment. And for that matter, you ought to have a test (or even dev!) environment where you could try stuff like `sleep` and find out what it does.

Comment: I actually did test select sleep in our test env by doing sleep(60), then trying to perform selects which worked just fine. But i just wanted to make sure as sometimes things can be overlooked or testing can be done wrong, hence giving you unwanted results. So to me specific, will running select sleep(60) as shown in my original post have any impact in production?

Comment: @TheGeorgia I wouldn't expect it to, other than using a connection. But I don't routinely use sleep in production (or at all) so I can't say for sure.